# need xhtml2pdf (Pisa 3.0) css syntax for @page and @frame

Tags: python, css, django, pdf-generation, pisa

i'm trying stuff out with xhtml2pdf (aka Pisa 3.0) and django and am having trouble with the css
http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/doc/pisa-en.html
obviously the docs above talk about the css that is available as well as vendor specific tags.

If i follow the example in the docs for static frames and make css like

```
@page{
        margin:0cm;
        @frame header{
            -pdf-frame-content: header;
            height: 3cm;    
        }
        @frame footer{
            -pdf-frame-content: footer;
            bottom: 2cm;
            height: 2cm;
        }
    }

    .main_content{
        padding: 0px
    }
    #header{

        background-color: #02164c;
        font: #FFFFFF;
        width:100%;     
    }
    #footer{    
        width: 100%;            
    }
    .pageBreak{
        page-break-after: always;       
    }
```

I get an error in django

Exception Value:

> Ruleset opening '{' not found::
>   (u'@page{\n\t\tmargin:',
>   u'0cm;\n\t\t@frame header')
>
> Exception Location:
>     /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/sx/w3c/cssParser.py
>   in _parseAtPage, line 654

it looks like the css parser is croaking on @page.
To me it looks like i'm using it as in the examples. I'm hoping someone can help provide some guidance on this or point me to some template examples.
I also am wondering how to use the -pdf- vendor specific tags. there is no documentation on these tags that i can find...

Comment: Checked this against a pdf i generate (which gave the same error) the only thing i could see was the lack of a space after @page{ - i changed it to @page { and your code works for me. Any help?

Comment: @JamesO - wow. that was awesome. wth. yes it was the whitespace that was killing it. If you want to move your comment to an answer i will happily award it to you as there is no way i would've tried that on my own. On a side note, any additional resources on vendor specific tags and/or @page and @frame tags?

Comment: will do, glad it helped. Not sure about additional docs for vendor tags, I've only used the ones used in the examples at the link above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@page{` seems to cause an error when there is no whitespace before the `{` changing to `@page {` works.